# Having different font in math formula

Tags: math-mode

I am looking for a proper and fast way to do something like in pictures I uploaded. I want to know how should I do those highlighted text.
[image]

Comment: erh, that is just `\mathsf{SetUp}(\lambda)` etc

Comment: what does erh mean ? :)